# How to use the Paypal Dialog?

Tags: javascript, paypal

I want to know how I can get this Paypal Dialog? Or if it's exclusive to Facebook… ?

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: Simple integration: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081967/paypal-integration-to-existing-website/8084289#8084289

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's PayPal Digital Goods for Express Checkout or Digital Goods for Adaptive Payments.
In essence, it's a pretty layer on top of an existing Express Checkout or Adaptive Payments integration meant for digital goods sales only.

PayPal has info about Digital Goods up on https://www.paypal.com/digitalgoods/ as well as https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/use-cases/digital-goods