# PayPal Integration to Existing Website

Tags: paypal

I am looking for a simple way to integrate PayPal to my existing , non-profit , website . I tried following the exact steps as provided by PayPal ( https://www.paypal-labs.com/integrationwizard/ecpaypal/code.php ) , but haven't been successful in making it work . Maybe I'm missing out on key connections between pages , but I'm clueless .

Any help ( tutorials , examples , step-by-step guidelines ... ) will be appreciated .

Regards !

Comment: You really need to provide more information.  What exactly isn't working?  Any error messages?  Are you unsure about a specific point of the steps involved?

Answer (score 0):

If you use PHP, you could use the [PHP Payment Library](http://www.phpfour.com/blog/2009/02/php-payment-gateway-library-for-paypal-authorizenet-and-2checkout/):

It is very easy to configure:

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="payment/paypal_start.php">
    <input type="text" name="item_name" />
    <input type="text" name="amount">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**paypal_start.php**

(start snippet 1 - total of 6 snippets)

```
// Include the paypal library
include_once ('Paypal.php');

// Create an instance of the paypal library
$myPaypal = new Paypal();

// Specify your paypal email
$myPaypal->addField('business', 'your@mail.com');

// Specify the currency
$myPaypal->addField('currency_code', 'EUR');
...
```